# JUnit AfterClass equivalent in Midje Clojure?

Tags: unit-testing, clojure, lisp, clojurescript, midje

I could not find any **Midje** function that runs after all facts.

**Here is the code:**

```
(background
  (before :contents (println "Before All Facts"))
  (after :contents (println "After All Facts"))
  (before :facts (println "Before Each Fact"))
  (after :facts (println "After Each Fact")))
```

**Actual** Output is:

```
Before All Facts
After All Facts
Before Each Fact
After Each Fact
```

**Expected** Output is:

```
Before All Facts
Before Each Fact
After Each Fact
After All Facts
```

Comment: Here is the github issue: https://github.com/marick/Midje/issues/374

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a question, but a bug -- one which the author feels cannot be fixed apparently, at least according to your github issue.

Comment: It's a bug in a deprecated feature, `background`.  The feature has been replaced with `with-state-changes` and `namespace-state-changes`, which do support what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap all your facts in a [`with-state-changes`](https://github.com/marick/Midje/wiki/Setup-and-teardown#nesting) to achieve this, but beware that Clojure has a limit to the maximum size of a top-level form.  To avoid that problem you can use [`namespace-state-changes`](https://github.com/marick/Midje/wiki/Setup-and-teardown#repl-and-whole-file-support) to perform setup and teardown at the beginning and end of an entire file.

Comment: I need AfterClass not After :) I guess Midje does not support this.

Comment: You can run code after all your facts this way, producing the output in your question. It won't be possible to interrupt execution after the actual namespace has been executed. Why do you need to do that?

Comment: Those links have good examples, I'm not sure I could add much I'm afraid.  You could also investigate moving away from midje and using fixtures from clojure.test with the `:once` flag

Comment: Essentially you just need to replace `background` with `with-state-changes` and put all the before/after forms in a vector